# Angular directive triggering the event twice

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling, jquery-events

I am creating a slide-in directive to display some options. In title there are 3 buttons namely, 'Back', 'deselectall' and 'Apply'. Now when I click on any of the button the 'click' event is fired twice. Please look at the following code.

HTML:

```
<aside class="search-filter-slide fullheight search-filter ng-hide">
        <div class="search-filter-by clearfix row" id="searchFiltersAction">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left" id="searchFilterBackBtn">Back</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link" id="deselectAllFilters">deselect all</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" id="applyFiltersBtn">Apply</button>
        </div>
</aside>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('MyAppObj')
.directive('searchFilter', [function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'CA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $(document).on('click','#searchFilterBtn.search-filter-btn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(element).removeClass('ng-hide');
              setTimeout(function () { $(element).addClass('slide-in'); }, 200);
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #searchFilterBackBtn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Closing the open filters view...',e.target.tagName)
              $(element).removeClass('slide-in');
              setTimeout(function () { $(element).addClass('ng-hide'); }, 500);
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #deselectAllFilters',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Deselect all selected filters...')
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #applyFiltersBtn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Apply selected filters to the search results...')
          });
      }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the directive twice ? If you put a breakpoint on the first line of the link method, does it get hit twice ?

Comment: Since you are attaching all of these to the document, any time you load this directive into the app, those events will be rebound. Is this HTML snippet behind some kind of `ng-if`? If so, each time the `ng-if` evalutes to true, a new event will be bound for all of these.

Comment: @BillBergquist - You have correctly guess the root cause of the issue. But now the question is how to handle such situation? As I have to use the directive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully tackle the scenario. Answering my question so that it can help someone:

Updated directive code:

```
angular.module('MyAppObj')
.directive('searchFilter', [function () {
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        $(document).on('click','#searchFilterBtn.search-filter-btn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(element).removeClass('ng-hide');
              setTimeout(function () { $(element).addClass('slide-in'); }, 200);
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #searchFilterBackBtn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Closing the open filters view...',e.target.tagName)
              $(element).removeClass('slide-in');
              setTimeout(function () { $(element).addClass('ng-hide'); }, 500);
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #deselectAllFilters',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Deselect all selected filters...')
          });

          $(document).on('click','#searchFiltersAction #applyFiltersBtn',function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              console.log('Apply selected filters to the search results...')
          });

          var cleanup = function(){
            $(document).off('click','#searchFilterBtn.search-filter-btn');
            $(document).off('click','#searchFiltersAction #searchFilterBackBtn');
            $(document).off('click','#searchFiltersAction #deselectAllFilters');
            $(document).off('click','#searchFiltersAction #applyFiltersBtn');
          }

          scope.$on('$destroy',cleanup)
    }
  return {
      restrict: 'CA',
      link: link
  };
 }]);
```